# In JavaScript, how do I get the full path including data after the trailing pound?

Tags: javascript

My full URL is

```
/settings/logs#/extra
```

but `window.location.pathname` just returns

```
/settings/logs
```

In the browser, how do I get the full path including the `#` and the information after it?

Comment: window.location.pathname + window.location.hash

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.location.href` to obtain the full url (with protocol, host, etc.) or concat the `window.location.pathname` with `window.location.hash` if you only need the "path".

```js
console.log(window.location.href); // Result: https://www.google.com/path/#hash
console.log(window.location.pathname + window.location.hash); // Result: /path/#hash
```

See [Location API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)

Answer (score 0):

Try `window.location.href` 
For further info:

```
https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-get-current-url-in-javascript.html
```